# CTE Recursive Query to fill in a Sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

Within this TSQL CTE, I'm trying to build a list of invoices that recursively that start with the parent version , down to Ver 1 for each invoice.

```
With
  myList
  AS (Select 10000 as INVOICE, 3 as VER
      UNION ALL
      Select 20000 as INVOICE, 5 as VER
      UNION ALL
      Select 30000 as INVOICE, 8 as VER
      UNION ALL
      Select 40000 as INVOICE, 2 as VER)
 ,newList (Invoice, Ver)
  AS (Select
       L1.Invoice
      ,L1.Ver
      from
       myList L1
      UNION ALL
      Select
       L2.Invoice
      ,L2.Ver - 1 Ver
      from
       myList L2
      Join
       newList L3
       on L2.invoice = L3.Invoice and L2.VER = L3.VER
      Where
       L2.Ver > = 1 )
 Select * from newList order by INVOICE, VER desc
```

A select on 'myList' will give you:

```
Invoice Ver
10000   3
20000   5
30000   8
40000   2
```

And what I hope to achieve is:

```
Invoice Ver
10000   3
10000   2
10000   1
20000   5
20000   4
20000   3
20000   2
20000   1
30000   8
30000   7
30000   6
30000   5
30000   4
30000   3
30000   2
30000   1
40000   2
40000   1
```

I've tried many variations (and of course not the right one!) but the best I can do is achieve only the 2nd level...

```
Invoice Ver
10000   3
10000   2
20000   5
20000   4
30000   8
30000   7
40000   2
40000   1
```

Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a recursive CTE for this, in each recursive call need to decrement the `ver` column

```
With myList
AS 
(     Select 10000 as INVOICE, 3 as VER
      UNION ALL
      Select 20000 as INVOICE, 5 as VER
      UNION ALL
      Select 30000 as INVOICE, 8 as VER
      UNION ALL
      Select 40000 as INVOICE, 2 as VER
 )
 ,newList (Invoice, Ver)
  AS 
 (
    SELECT INVOICE, VER from myList
    UNION ALL
    SELECT INVOICE, VER-1 FROM newList
    WHERE VER >1
  )
  SELECT * FROM newList order by INVOICE, VER desc
```

Comment: haha - thought I was doing exactly what you said I needed to do. I suppose the Microsoft Example threw me off since both legs of it's CTE reference the anchor query. Regardless, well done!